# PostgreSQL : ERROR: function geta(integer, integer, unknown) does not exist

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I am creating a dynamic query generation function which helped me out in my work. The `CREATE FUNCTION` script parsed successfully but i am not able execute it. While executing the function, it shows an error.

I have tried a lot.

Please look below for code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."GetA" (headcategoriesid int4,cdfid int4,
colName text) 
RETURNS varchar AS

$BODY$

DECLARE
   sql1 text := 'select string_agg(answer, '','') as HeadName from 
   ' || $3 || 'where  cdfid = ' || $2 || ' and headcategoriesid = '|| $1;

BEGIN

  -- RETURN QUERY
   Execute sql1;

-- 'select string_agg(answer, '','') as HeadName from ' || $3 || 
   'where  cdfid = ' || $2 || ' and headcategoriesid = '|| $1;

 --  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
 --   'select string_agg(answer, '','') as HeadName from  %I WHERE 
       cdfid = %L and  headcategoriesid = %L', colName,   7, 96
 -- );
END

$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Am using **Postgresql 9.2.4**

Comment: Please include the text of the function, not a screenshot. Very hard to read.

Comment: Also, **include the full, exact text of the error message** (again, copy and paste) please. Along with your PostgreSQL version - `SELECT version()`.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit

Comment: @CraigRinger Pls check for code

Comment: today morning I created 2-3 functions with same owner

Comment: You forgot to add the code that uses the function and the **exact** error message that you get.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Which code need to add ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call function as below:

```
SELECT "GetA"(7,96,'educationdetails'::text);
```

when you call the function GetA without ""(quotes) than it will be considerd as geta (small letter). but in your code  you are using "" so it is created as GetA.

Comment: Again error occured as ERROR: function geta(integer, integer, text) does not exist

Comment: You also need to cast 7 and 96 to int4 or you can take them as integer in the procedure.

Comment: Same error for "SELECT GetA(7::int4,96::int4,'educationdetails'::text);"

Comment: check my edits. when you use GetA without "" than it will be considerd as geta. but when you create procedure than you are using "" so it is GetA.

Comment: Error : "control reached end of function without RETURN"

Comment: your procedure return type is varchar and you are not returning anything.

Comment: Its nt showing any error but , returning blank value.... is that any reason fr that

Comment: @CraigRinger Its working now... Try with Execute Format